# What is the point of TEXMFLOCAL anyway?

Tags: texlive, texmf-local

So I'm doing my bimonthly install of jaxodraw ([check it out!](https://jaxodraw.sourceforge.io/)) on some machine or another, which requires the LateX style file axodraw4j.sty. I tried the thing I always do:

```
# kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/share/texmf-local
# cp /home/cduston/Downloads/axodraw4j.sty /usr/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/
# texhash
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-config/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-local/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-var/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

And I think this matters too:

```
 more ls-R
% ls-R -- filename database for kpathsea; do not change this line.
./:
.:
ls-R
tex


./tex:
latex

./tex/latex:
axodraw4j.sty
```

But, no matter what I do, I cannot get users on my system to ever be able to use axodraw4j.sty unless I put it NOT in TEXMFLOCAL, but in HOME:

$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/cduston/texmf

But like, I don't want it there, and I can't figure out why I need to clutter up my home directory with that nonesense. TEXMFLOCAL is completely empty, why would texlive require permissions like that? I should be able to READ /usr/share/texmf-local fine right? Why can't my tex installation *ever* see style files in that directory?

EDIT: From comments:

```
$ ls /usr/share/texmf-local/tex/latex
axodraw4j.sty
$ kpsewhich axodraw4j.sty
/usr/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
/usr/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
```

More:

```
$ ls -la
-rw-r----- 1 root root 70021 Jul 29 14:09 axodraw4j.sty
texmf-local/tex/latex$ kpsewhich axodraw4j.sty
./axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
./axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
/usr/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
/usr/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
```

Comment: User-created TeX files should be in `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/local` to be found automatically by the LaTeX programs with the default settings.

Comment: @musarithmia That's not the question. And if you you want files to be found by multiple users on the same machine, then `TEXMFLOCAL` is the correct place for them.

Comment: When you install the package and do the first method, what does `kpsewhich axodraw4j.sty` return?

Comment: On [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.5), try to follow this section _3.4.6 Integrating local and personal macros_. It turns out you need an **up-to-date ﬁlename database**. Apparently, `mktexlsr` is the command to do so. More about directories in _3.2.3 Directories_ and _2.3 Overview of the predeﬁned texmf trees_.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Same permission problem, see my edit.

Comment: @Celdor: I will look at that section, but at a glance mktexlsr has same permission problems: $ mktexlsr
mktexlsr: /usr/share/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/share/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/share/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/share/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: Done.

(being root gets permissions, but does not change that users cannot access it)

Comment: @Celdor `texhash` is an alternative name for `mktexlsr`.

Comment: what happens if you run it as root `sudo mktexlsr`?

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks. I didn't know that. I was merely following the instructions on their website.

Comment: @Celdor that page is detailing the upstream texlive from TUG, levitophr is using a linux packaged tex, so managed with a linux package manager such as `apt`

Comment: @celder: running either texhash or mktexlsr does access those directories, but does not change that fact that they are not found by kpsewhich or invocations of latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I don't know how to help with such a version of TeX. In future cases, how do you recognise the TeX distribution is installed from the OS repository? Thanks

Comment: @AlanMunn I mean, I copied the .sty file in there as root:
-rw-r----- 1 root root 70021 Jul 29 14:09 axodraw4j.sty
even if I'm *in* the directory /tex/latex I still get:
texmf-local/tex/latex$ kpsewhich axodraw4j.sty
./axodraw4j.sty: Permission denied
Should I change the permissions on the actual .sty? That seems very wrong...

Comment: @Celdor: well, I did mention texlive in my answer, which is the (I think) most common distribution of tex.

Comment: @levitopher no we are using texlive as origially packaged by TUG which is the page Celdor referecenced, you are using a re-packaged version by one of the linux distribs but you have not said which one.

Comment: @levitopher `I copied the .sty file in there as root: -rw-r----- 1 root root 70021 Jul 29 14:09 axodraw4j.sty`  Well that is clearly the cause of your error, you have made the file only readable by root so no user can use it. So it is an error in that file copy, not a problem with the tex distribution,

Comment: @Celdor vanilla texlive installs in /usr/local/texlive/2022 not /usr/share (it is possible to change that but that would be unlikely here)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is Slackware, but the exact same thing happens in Ubuntu ( and Pop_OS!, which is just Ubuntu....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And yes, I guess your suggestion fixed it....chmod a+w blah blah blah. But the original file was <useraccount> users, so copying it as root changed it to root root....I get that's the problem. THANKS!

Comment: @levitopher most of the linux versions are similar, and use the same sources as upstream TUG texlive but repackage to fit the system package manager (so `apt` for debian/ubuntu flavoured linux) and change default directory structure to match the system conventions. so "slackware" would probably have been useful info as your question is about directory and install paths not tex itself. Linux texlive is fine for most users although regulars here often want the cutting edge so ignore that and install from tug (or from source) even on linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If copying a file to TEXMFLOCAL so available for all users, it needs to be readable by all users

```
root: -rw-r----- 1 root root 70021 Jul 29 14:09 axodraw4j.sty
```

is only readable by root so not readable by any user account.

Comment: Yes this is the right answer - I was just slightly surprised because I'm used to copying binaries into places like /usr/local as root, and then just running them since they are in my path. But whoever created the binaries probably expected that, and has set the owner to 1001 (or whatever trickery they used), and the creators (zippers?) of this style file did not do a similar thing. Anyway, linux thing in the end, not Tex thing....